# Regular Expression check only once for a single character and contains more then one number?

Tags: regex

I would like to build up a regex expression that checks in the text if the string contains a single dot between numbers and that there are more then one number.

My text example would be:

```
11.00 11.000 1.0 1 1 2.
```

I would like to check that text contains only single dot and I would to check text contains more then one number either 1 or like this 111.00. How can I do this.

My current expression checks for more then one dot and it not checking if the text contains more then one value of the correct format 1.1 or 1. Also I am checking for new lines and any number of spaces as follows:

```
/^[0-9 .\n\t]*$/
```

Comment: Try a pattern like `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+\.$`

Comment: I lost you at *"more then one number either 1 or..."*

Comment: the text most contains more then one number and these numbers can be with dots or without

Comment: numbers can be like 1.0 11.00 or 1 2 3 if its with dots may contains more digits on both side left hand and right hand like this 11.00

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: If the dot at the end of the example string is a typo and it is not there, remove `\.` at the end of the regex in the top comment, `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+$`

Comment: Thank you for your reply I did add some conditions to it where to include spaces and new lines.

Comment: So, does it work? Shall I post as an answer? I see no conditions anywhere.

Comment: Yes please do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zvaWWa/1).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of `.` and one or more digits
- `(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+` - **one or more** occurrences of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of
- `$` - end of string